# Simple: Mercurial Tags Usage

Tags: version-control, mercurial, tags, workflow

Disclaimer: I am a Mercurial noob with a shallow background in CVS. I have searched quite a bit and can't seem to find a clear answer, so here it goes. I am attempting to work out a simple default-stable named branch work flow in Mercurial. I understand that when you tag a change set, the act of tagging is itself a change and is committed. Let's say I am here:
[image: Help]

I got here by running

```
hg update 0.1.0_Beta
```

fixing a bug, and committing the fix.

**Scenarios:**

1. I did something wrong

   Q: What did I do wrong / What should I have done?
2. Right so far...

   Q: What do I do now?

Comment: I suppose I could just merge both heads of stable, resolve the two heads issue, and just continue on my way, but is this the "correct" way?

Comment: I should have said "correct" but "ugly" way*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After experimenting a bit, it seems like I didn't really do anything wrong, and that merging the two heads is the right way to continue.  I think that the single floating change set just sort of threw me off looking at it. If the bugfix is in the last stable change then updating to the tip of stable might make sense. I am still unsure of whether or not it is worth it to fix bugs deeper in the history unless there is a specific need to (customer support or what-have-you). I'm going to accept this answer unless someone else leads me to something better.

Answer (score 0):

You're in great shape. There's nothing you need to do.  Tags are automatically "read" from all 'heads' so there's no need to merge the head on stable that creates the tag (`4c84...`) into anything else.   When you do `hg stable` you'll get `acf8...` and when you do `hg update default` you'll get `3449....`.  Rock on.

Comment: I think that he's complaining about the fact that changeset `157f6f` is tagged as `0.1.0_Beta` by its child changeset `4c8485` and when he updated to that tag and committed another change the tagging changeset was left hanging.  He now has two heads on `stable` which do need merging before he would be allowed to push.  I think that what he really wanted when he issued the `hg up 0.1.0_Beta` was to be given the tagging changeset instead of the tagged one which would have left him with only one head on stable.

Comment: I understood the desire.  He can certainly merge the two heads on `stable` together, but it's not required.   Better would have been to avoid creating the new head entirely by just doing the typo fix off of the existing head on `stable` rather than updating back to the tag.  Either way, this was a conceptual hurdle and he or she seems to have now lept it.